# How to pass a compile flag to cmake initial compiler test?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, msp430

I'm trying to use CMake for building a project which uses the [MSPGCC cross-compiler](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mspgcc/index.php?title=MSPGCC_Wiki) for a MSP430 microcontroller. To successfully compile any simple program with it, we need to pass a compile flag indicating the target processor, or else it fails like this:

```
$ msp430-gcc -o test test.c
In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/include/msp430.h:813:2: warning: #warning Unable to identify and include MCU header, use -mmcu=MCU [-Wcpp]
/usr/local/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file memory.x: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Hence, if I indicate the processor using the `-mmcu` switch it works fine. The problem is, although I'm already specifying this in my **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (test-project C)

set (SOURCES
  test.c
  )

add_executable (test-project ${SOURCES})
set (CPU_FLAG "-mmcu=msp430f148")

set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CPU_FLAG})
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CPU_FLAG})
```

CMake complains the compiler failed the test to compile a simple program, which I bet is happening because it is probably **not using** the `-mmcu` switch (note the message about not being able to open linker script file memory.x):

```
$ cd ~/git/test-project
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../msp430.cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/msp430-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/msp430-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "/usr/local/bin/msp430-gcc" is not able to compile a simple
  test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/claudio/git/test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:/usr/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec2889462763/fast"

  /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889462763.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889462763.dir/build

  gmake[1]: Entering directory
  `/home/claudio/git/test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
  /home/claudio/git/test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

  Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889462763.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /usr/local/bin/msp430-gcc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889462763.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /home/claudio/git/test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2889462763

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889462763.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

  /usr/local/bin/msp430-gcc
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889462763.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o
  cmTryCompileExec2889462763 -rdynamic

  /usr/local/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cannot open
  linker script file memory.x: No such file or directory

  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

  gmake[1]: Leaving directory
  `/home/claudio/git/test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec2889462763] Error 1

  gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec2889462763/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Just for the record, my toolchain file is as follows, and my PATH variable allows it to find the compiler binaries at `/usr/local/bin`:

```
# the name of the target operating system
#SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which C and C++ compiler to use
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   msp430-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER msp430-g++) 

# here is the target environment located
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/local/msp430) 

# adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search headers and libraries in the target environment, search 
# programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

All that said, can anyone tell me how to check which compile flags CMake is using to carry the compiler test, and how can we pass custom flags (like `-mmcu`, for instance) so it doesn't fail it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Docs:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file

you should use the CMakeForceCompiler thing

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME eCos)

# specify the cross compiler
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-elf-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(arm-elf-g++ GNU)

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /home/alex/src/ecos/install )

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

(copy&paste from the docs)

Using it fine here for my MSP430 too

Comment: when I was using MSPGCC4 it did work out fine too, but now that I'm using the newer MSPGCC it is failing the compiler test (MSPGCC4 was discontinued and development turned back to the original project). The `INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)` unfortunately had no effect.

Comment: It's not just the include it's also the two lines CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-elf-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(arm-elf-g++ GNU) - you also have them?

Comment: Yes, that was it! I didn't notice CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER was actually in place of CMAKE_C_COMPILER. This does override the compiler test instead of making it use the -mmcu switch, right? Thanks!

Comment: **This answer is outdated.** Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949645/2137996) below.

Answer (score 4):

**The other answer here is outdated.**

The toolchain file should include the required flags in the appropriate `CMAKE_<KIND>_FLAGS(_<CONFIG>)_INIT` variables, like so:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "-mmcu=msp430f148")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-mmcu=msp430f148")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-mmcu=msp430f148")
```

CMake's compiler detection routines will use these flags when compiling a test executable. The full list is available in the [CMake variables documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html), but the full list (at time of writing) is:

- `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT`
- `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_INIT`
- `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT`
- `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`
- `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT`
- `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`
- `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT`
- `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`
- `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT`
- `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`

Where `<CONFIG>` is any ALL CAPS config name including, but not limited to, `DEBUG`, `RELWITHDEBINFO`, `MINSIZEREL`, and `RELEASE`. The non-`<CONFIG>` variants apply to *all* configurations and are *augmented* by the `<CONFIG>` variants.

And, where `<LANG>` is any of the languages known to `enable_language()`, currently including `CXX`, `C`, `CUDA`, `OBJC`, `OBJCXX`, `Fortran`, `HIP`, `ISPC`, and `ASM`. The current list may be found in the [`enable_language` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html).