# CMake, GNU, and STM32: _exit Link Error when Testing Compiler

Tags: cmake, arm, stm32

I'm porting code from IAR on Windows for an STM32F4 to OSX/GNU/CMake.

I've defined a toolchain file ARM.cmake to use arm-none-eabi-g++/gcc. When I run cmake (referencing the toolchain file) I get an error when it tries to link the simple test program. It complains that _exit() is not defined.

I understand that exit() is being called and it calls _exit() which it expects to find elsewhere. Perhaps when I eventually link against my RTOS it will have this defined or perhaps I have to define it myself. In the meantime how do I get past the compiler checks?

> set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
>
> set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STM32F407)
>
> set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
>
> set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)

Answer (score 2):

Including the CMake include file CMakeForceCompiler and using the "FORCE" macros solved the problem. Answered indirectly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147256/873389).

> include(CMakeForceCompiler)
>
> set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
>
> set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STM32F407)
>
> CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
>
> CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-g++ GNU)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need or want syscalls, you can use `nosys.specs`.

Here's a snippet from our `arm-gcc` [CMake toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) targeting Cortex-M:

```
string(CONCAT CM4_LINK_FLAGS
    "--specs=nosys.specs "  # firmware has no syscall implementation
    "-lnosys "              # syscalls are empty stubs
    "-lc"                   # libc with nosys.spec uses newlib-nano
    )

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CM4_LINK_FLAGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

If this is in your toolchain file, you can load it from the command line by invoking CMake with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path-to-your-toolchain>`. Since it's loaded before your first `project` directive, CMake uses these flags during compiler exploration and its small test files will compile and link successfully.

Alternately, skip compiler exploration entirely with:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS ON)
```

You're explicitly setting your known compiler for a fixed architecture; maybe you're also explicitly setting your flags and don't need CMake to interrogate your toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty function void _exit(int status) {}. Check here if you want more info: http://stm32discovery.nano-age.co.uk/open-source-development-with-the-stm32-discovery/getting-newlib-to-work-with-stm32-and-code-sourcery-lite-eabi

Comment: Thanks. I understand how this would help link my application but will this get me past the compiler checks cmake performs? I'm not sure I understand how the checks would be aware of some object file or library I created that contains my empty _exit().

Comment: And I apologize: I haven't yet read the link. I'll do that tomorrow when I resume this project. Thought I'd get the question in the hopper in case my original post was not clear.

Comment: If you're at the linking stage, then your source is already checked by the compiler and compiled. Or am I missing something?

Comment: CMake seems to have some test file that it compiles as a check before it gets started. Maybe it's an empty main or something. I should be clear and state that it fails the compile/link step when testing the C/C++ compilers. CMake then bails out with an error and my project make files are not generated. If I were to get past this step then I can add my _exit() definition and my project will link OK. Just not sure how to tell the test code to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE to STATIC_LIBRARY skips the linking step, and solves problems with both missing functions during linking and missing linker files.

So in the toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

(Forcing the compiler is a deprecated function and should be avoided if possible)